# C# How to calculate working days excluding specific dates (Holidays)

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime, date-arithmetic

I read some questions/answers related to functions in C# to calculate the working days (Days from Mondays to Fridays); some uses an extended code to achieve that.

I have a data table with more than 50,000 rows and I required an effective method to calculate this information.

Comment: To be clear - are you looking to find all the holidays during a certain year (then you can just calculate the hours lost from those days), or are you looking for the number of hours in a working year?

Comment: 50,000 rows of... what? And what is your source of holiday information? Also, showing what you tried tends to clarify a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/// <summary> Get working days between two dates (Excluding a list of dates - Holidays) </summary>
/// <param name="dtmCurrent">Current date time</param>
/// <param name="dtmFinishDate">Finish date time</param>
/// <param name="lstExcludedDates">List of dates to exclude (Holidays)</param>
public static int fwGetWorkingDays(this DateTime dtmCurrent, DateTime dtmFinishDate, List<DateTime> lstExcludedDates)
{
    Func<DateTime, bool> workDay = currentDate =>
            (
                currentDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday ||
                currentDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ||
                lstExcludedDates.Exists(evalDate => evalDate.Date.Equals(currentDate.Date))
            );

    return Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + (dtmFinishDate - dtmCurrent).Days).Count(intDay => workDay(dtmCurrent.AddDays(intDay)));
}
```

I created this extension that basically takes two dates and a list of dates to exclude (Holidays).
Surprisingly this method is very fast and has a validation to exclude the time from the DateTime when compare against the list of exclusions.

Comment: Depends what is the definition of "Working Day".  Public holidays are not considered working day.  I do what you have done PLUS I keep a list of public holidays for each year for the next few years for a particular type of organization the software serves.  If you add that public holiday check to your code, you get a TRUE working day calculator. Not a big burden to spend 10 min to enter 10-12 rows for a few years in future in a db table.

Comment: I'm surprised, the definition of workDay is inverted... I have rewritten it (with second's answer syntax for excluded dates):

        Func<DateTime, bool> workDay = currentDate => (
         currentDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday &&
         currentDate.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday &&
         !excludedDates.Contains(currentDate.Date));

Furthermore, I didn't add the "+1" in "return Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + (" because I consider fully past days only and am looking at calculating the diff in the morning, at start of business day to know whether I'm late.

Answer (score 8):

Based on @MiBols answer a more efficient solution will be to use a `HashSet<DateTime>` instead of a `List<DateTime>` where search is then in `O(1)`:

```
/// <summary> Get working days between two dates (Excluding a list of dates - Holidays) </summary>
/// <param name="dtmCurrent">Current date time</param>
/// <param name="dtmFinishDate">Finish date time</param>
/// <param name="excludedDates">Collection of dates to exclude (Holidays)</param>
public static int fwGetWorkingDays(this DateTime dtmCurrent, DateTime dtmFinishDate, 
                                   HashSet<DateTime> excludedDates)
{
    Func<DateTime, bool> workDay = currentDate => (
        currentDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday ||
        currentDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ||
        excludedDates.Contains(currentDate.Date));

    return Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + (dtmFinishDate - dtmCurrent).Days)
        .Count(intDay => workDay(dtmCurrent.AddDays(intDay)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static int ToBusinessWorkingDays(this DateTime start, DateTime due, DateTime[] holidays)
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(0, (due - start).Days)
                            .Select(a => start.AddDays(a))
                            .Where(a => a.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                            .Where(a => a.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                            .Count(a => !holidays.Any(x => x == a));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a mix of two soutions above, inverting the expression to verify workDay and checking if the difference is negative.

```
public static int GetWorkingDaysUntil(this DateTime dtmCurrent, DateTime dtmFinishDate, HashSet<DateTime> excludedDates)
{
    Func<DateTime, bool> workDay = currentDate => !(currentDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday ||
                                                    currentDate.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ||
                                                    excludedDates.Contains(currentDate.Date));

    var daysDifference = (dtmFinishDate - dtmCurrent).Days;

    return daysDifference > 0 ?
                Enumerable.Range(0, 1 + daysDifference).Count(intDay => workDay(dtmCurrent.AddDays(intDay))) :
                0;
}
```