# Subtract DateTime in C# exluding weekends AND holidays

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datetime

I'm creating an API and I need to subtract a certain number of periods and make sure I only quantify business days (excluding weekends and holidays) but I'm having trouble.

I've found some useful solutions to only capture weekdays when I subtract from dateTime.Now() but I need to exclude US federal holidays as well.

Comment: What trouble are you having? What have you tried?

Comment: The duplicate shows how to do this provided you already have a list of holidays as a List<DateTime> or HashSet<DateTime>

Comment: This should not have been closed as a duplicate, since the duplicate is only about excluding weekends. This question also asks about excluding US federal holidays. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: There is a free to use library on NuGet named TimePeriodLibrary.NET which is perfect for solving this kind of problem.

Comment: @Bent [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43480738/3181933) seems to address excluding specific holidays.

Comment: That question does not. Furthermore, the answer(s) deal with excluding days supplied in a list. There is no answer that deals with excluding US federal holidays. So the question remains; how to retrieve US federal holidays. There may be interesting answers to that question.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably just scroll it with a loop, repeatedly adding or subbing a period and testing upon each add/sub if the current day is banned, sub a whole day:

```
  DateTime ScrollSkipping(DateTime start, TimeSpan period, int numPeriods, HashSet<DateTime> hashsetOfPublicHolidays){
    
    var d = start; //eg new DateTime(2021, 12, 26, 0, 30, 0);
    var t = period; //eg -1 hour to go backwards
    var skip = TimeSpan.FromDays(period<TimeSpan.Zero?-1:1);
    var p = numPeriods; // eg 25 times

    for(int x = 0; x < p;){
      if(d.DayOfWeek is DayOfWeek.Saturday or DayOfWeek.Sunday || hashsetOfPublicHolidays.Contains(d.Date))
        d += skip;
      else{
        d += t; 
        x++;
      }
    }
  }
```

If you supplied a `TimeSpan.FromHours(-1);` as the period and 25 as the number of periods, and don't "use up" a period when you're skipping whole days for some reason, then resume decrementing it when you're back on a normal date then you'll skip completely over the weekends/holidays.

To go backwards supply a negative TimeSpan as the period, forwards positive

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need to know the 'US Federal holidays' There are some paid APIS that provide those data or as US holidays ar very simple, use a list built from this: https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/5/6103